# Как реализовать постоянный парсинг в плагине нескольких страниц

Tags: javascript

Пишу расширение,смог реализовать парсинг нужной мне инфы со страницы.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var data = xhr.responseText;
    var example = document.getElementById('example');
    example.innerHTML = data;

    var name = document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_item_name")[0].innerHTML;
    var priceO = document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee")[0].innerHTML;
    dannie.innerHTML = priceO;
    dannie.innerHTML = name + " : " + priceO; // добавляется в блок с id=dannie цена

  }

}
xhr.send();
```

Парсится цена с торговой площадки.
Но как реализовать,чтобы парсилось сразу несколько,штук 10-15 орудий и цена постоянно бы обновлялась(например каждые 30 секунд).

Для примера добавлю ещё парочку орудий
1.[Ещё одно орудие](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Frontside%20Misty%20%28Field-Tested%29)
2.[Вот ещё](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде подход к решению такого плана задачи называется **Short polling**, иными словами, Вы банально делаете запрос за в n секунд. Это что называется решение в лоб, в данном случае он **малоэффективно**, особенно если Вы будете использовать большое количество url, соответсвенно большое количество запросов.

Если изменения будут происходить менее чем раз в n секунд, вы рискуете тем, что будете гонять туда-сюда трафик, то есть полезная нагрузка в этом случае равняется нулю.

Тем не менее, образец, как это можно реализовать.

```
'use strict';

const URLS = [
  'http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29',
  'http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Frontside%20Misty%20%28Field-Tested%29',
  'http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29'
];

function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      if (event.status == 200) {
        const data = event.responseText;
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        const error = new Error(event.statusText);
        error.code = event.status;
        reject(error);
      }
    });

    xhr.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
      reject(new Error('Network Error'));
    });

    xhr.send();
  });
}

function parseURLS(URLS, timeout = 30) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    Promise.all(URLS.map(doRequest))
      .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((result) => {
          var example = document.getElementById('example');
          example.innerHTML = result;

          var name = document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_item_name")[0].innerHTML;
          var priceO = document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee")[0].innerHTML;
          dannie.innerHTML = priceO;
          dannie.innerHTML = name + " : " + priceO; // добавляется в блок с id=dannie цена
        });
      });
  }, timeout);
}

parseURLS(URLS);
```

Возможно, что для решения Вашей задачи, полезно будет изучить, какие возможности предоставляет Steam [API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=russian).

Comment: По-другому, вынести логику работы с запросами к Steam на сторону, скажем php, nodejs-клиента и уже к нему непосредственно обращаться. Но не раз в n секунд, а всякий раз, когда сервер отвечает. Возникнет такая ситуация, что в этом случае, Вы будете получать ответ только тогда, когда серверу "будет, что ответить" или будет превышен максимальный интервал ожидания запроса, который висит на сервере. Посмотрите информацию по **long polling**. В общих чертах, приблизительно так он и выглядит.

Comment: ,понял. Или же использовать steamAPI.

Comment: По Steam API предметно не могу ничего сказать, в ответе я всего лишь предположил, читайте документацию.